Where did my old question go?
I wrote a well sourced, well thought out question for the English StackExchange, and you guys didn't like it.  OK, whatever, you guys never like what I have to say, so that's not new.  I'd like to refer to that question though, as I linked to several sources, and I don't recall everything that I put into it.  I think I asked it within the past few months, but it may be closer to a year, I'm not sure.
I don't see it in my profile, which I expected, even if the question was downvoted to oblivion.
Where did it go?

If you go to your main user profile, click on Questions in the left hand menu, do you see it then? Do you have a "Deleted questions" link at the bottom of the list? Is your question in that link's list? [If you find it, this comment can form an answer; but if you've done all this and still can't see it, it's not an answer.]

ah there it is, it was deleted

Questions can be removed by a variety of means. An unnuanced list, which may not be exhaustive, includes

votes of the community
adverse flags
deletion or destruction of the poster's account on the site or network
the “Roomba”, a scheduled back-end script which clears up the site.

There's a Help page on the Roomba script: your question was cleared up under the last set of criteria, “If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...”
If you have 10k rep, you can find deleted questions in any user's main-site or meta profile [depending which site it was asked on]: click Questions in the menu under the profile image to see a list of questions they’ve asked. Deleted questions are included in the list.

On your own profile there is also a Deleted questions link at the bottom of the list which displays your own deleted questions in their own list.
